# SQL - Show records which meet 2 or more of multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table of many records.  I am trying to find a way to show the records which meet more than one condition of a query.  For example, if I had this table.

```
TABLE NAME: DATA

ID   contactid  flag        flag_type 
-----------------------------------
1     99         Volunteer   1 
2     99         Uploaded    2 
3    100         Via Import  3 
4    100         Volunteer   1  
5    100         Uploaded    2
```

with conditions such as:

```
WHERE (ID > 2) OR (flag = 'Uploaded') OR (flag_type = 1) ..etc..
```

The output would be where IDs 4 & 5 only would be returned.

Comment: Why 4,5 only why not 3,4,5 although 3 has also matched the where clause

Comment: I'm looking for a way to only show results which match at least 2 of the conditions. ID 3 would only meet `ID > 2`

Answer (score 5):

You can count the number of conditions in MySQL and use this value:

```
where ((id > 2) +
       (flag = 'Uploaded') +
       (flag_type = 1)
      ) > 1
```

A boolean value of "true" is treated as `1` AND "false" is treated as `0`.  So, by adding up the values, you get the number of conditions that are met.

Often, you do this in an `order by`, to get the most matching first:

```
where id > 2 or flag = 'Uploaded' or flag_type = 1
order by ((id > 2) +
          (flag = 'Uploaded') +
          (flag_type = 1)
         ) desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/572e1/11

This solution selects each of your successful conditions as 1 which is added to "factors". Then we show results with at least 2 factors:

```
SELECT * FROM
 (select id, contactid, flag, flag_type, 
   (CASE WHEN id > 2 then 1 else 0 END) +
   (CASE WHEN flag = 'Uploaded' then 1 else 0 END) +
   (CASE WHEN flag_type = 1 then 1 else 0 END) AS factors
   from DATA 
  ) t
WHERE factors > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

With your limited question, this is the most that can be provided.

```
WHERE `ID`>2 AND (`flag`='Uploaded' OR `flag_type`=1) ..etc
```

Comment: Thanks for this @f00644 There may be 10 conditions though, I'm trying to find a way where at least two conditions are matched, without needing to code every possible permutation as a condition

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path, but you need to read first about [boolean logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations).  ORs are going to return records that match *any* of the conditions and ANDs will return records that match *all* of the conditions.